# On sequences which converge to zero with respect to an operator ideal

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\mathcal{A}$ be an operator ideal. A sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X$ is called $\mathcal{A}$-convergent to zero if there exist an operator $S\in \mathcal{A}(Z,X)$ for some Banach space $Z$ and a sequence $(z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $Z$ converging to zero in norm such that $x_{n}=S(z_{n}),n=1,2,...$ We denote the set of all such sequences by $c^{\mathcal{A}}_{0}(X)$. My questions are the following:

$\bullet$ Is $c^{\mathcal{A}}_{0}(X)$ a Banach space with the sup norm?

$\bullet$ What is the dual space of $c^{\mathcal{A}}_{0}(X)$?

Answer (score 3):

Finite rank operators are in all operator ideals, so any finitely supported sequence of vectors from $X$ is always in $c^{\mathcal{A}}_{0}(X)$ regardless of the ideal $\mathcal{A}$. So if we endow $c^{\mathcal{A}}_{0}(X)$ with the sup norm, it will only be complete when it is all of $c_0(X)$.

I would guess that taking the infimum of $\|(z_n)_{n=1}^\infty\|_{\infty} \cdot \|S\|_{\mathcal{A}}$ as the definition of the norm on $c^{\mathcal{A}}_{0}(X)$ might give rise to something interesting.

Comment: You are right,Alejandro. But I do not even know how to show that $c^{\mathcal{A}}_{0}(X)$ is a linear subspace of $c_{0}(X)$. Thank you very much.

Comment: Closure under $+$ is no problem, Dongyang.  If $x_n = Tw_n$ and $y_n = Sz_n$, $T:W\to X$, $S:Z \to X$, consider $S\oplus T: W\oplus Z \to X$ defined by $S\oplus T(w,z) = Sw + Tz$.

Comment: @BillJohnson: The problem is whether the operator $S\oplus T:W\oplus Z\rightarrow X$ is in $\mathcal{A}(W\oplus Z,X)$.

Comment: @DongyangChen: Consider the canonical projections $\pi_W$ and $\pi_Z$ defined on $W \oplus Z$. Then $S \oplus T$ is nothing but $T\circ\pi_W + S \circ \pi_Z$, which belongs to $\mathcal{A}$ because both $T$ and $S$ do.

Comment: @Alejandro:as you suggested,we can define the new norm on $c_{0}^{\mathcal{A}}(X)$ by taking the infimum. But it seems that the new norm does not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @DongyangChen given $(x_n),(y_n)$ take $(w_n),(z_n), T, S$ as in Bill's comment above, with the additional condition that $\|(w_n)\|_\infty = 1 = \|(z_n)\|_\infty$, $\|S\|_\mathcal{A} \le (1+\epsilon)\|(y_n)\|_{c_0^\mathcal{A}(X)}$, $\|T\|_\mathcal{A} \le (1+\epsilon)\|(x_n)\|_{c_0^\mathcal{A}(X)}$. Then $(w_n, z_n)$ and $S \oplus T : W \oplus_\infty Z \to X$ provide a representation for $(x_n+y_n)$ that gives the triangle inequality: $\|(w_n,z_n)\|_\infty=1$, whereas $\|S \oplus T\|_\mathcal{A} = \| T \circ \pi_W + S \circ \pi_Z\|_\mathcal{A} \le \|T\|_\mathcal{A} + \|S\|_\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @DongyangChen I do not know how to prove the completeness, though. If I remember correctly (this was a month ago), I was able to prove that $\ell_\infty^\mathcal{A}(X)$ is complete (with the obvious definition) but I couldn't see how to show that $c_0^\mathcal{A}(X)$ is a closed subset.

Comment: @Alejandro:Given $x\in c_{0}^{\mathcal{A}}(X)$, we have $\parallel x\parallel_{c_{0}(X)}\leq \parallel x\parallel_{c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)}$. Maybe we can use the completeness of $c_{0}(X)$ to prove the completeness of $c_{0}^{\mathcal {A}}(X)$. By the way, can you give the sketch of the proof of $l_{\infty}^{\mathcal A}(X)$?